# Missing checkbox when selecting layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm an absolute beginner to QGIS.

I'm trying to select BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops.dbf as a layer, but it does not have a checkbox in front of it as the DRUHIG_0096.tif.

How can I get the checkbox in front of the BRUNSWICK.dbf so that I can view it as a layer?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that file from and how did you load it? It's an attribute only table with no geometry. Those types of layers are usually .txt or .csv files. If yours has the extension .dbf, that makes me suspect that it is part of a shape file but has become separated from it's associated files. It should be stored with a .shp, .shx and .prj with the same name.

Comment: You just need to exit editing mode, that is, click the "Pencil" button on the toolbar, and if I'm not mistaken, then the file with the extension *.dbf impossible to view as a layer ... you can open it in any text editor ...

Comment: I do *not* recommend opening the original dbf file with a text editor, as you may accidentally corrupt the file. If you want to see what it looks like, make a copy, and open the copy in a text editor or spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 4):

.dbf files do not have any spatial information, they are simply a spreadsheet.

Thus they can be added to QGIS, but they cannot be displayed on the map, because there is nothing to display.

Answer (score 0):

A [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Overview) is composed of at least 3 separate files, one of which is the .dbf file.  The .dbf file is basically the attribute table, without any spatial information. Spatial information is stored in the .shp file.

Open the file where the shapefile is stored. (If you don't remember where the shapefile is stored, open the properties for the BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops layer (right click on the layer name in the layer panel > properties). In the Information tab, you'll see the file path. Copy and paste the file path into file explorer to open the file location.) Hopefully, that folder will contain at least these three files:

- BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops.dbf
- BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops.shp
- BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops.shx

If it does, you have a complete shapefile. **Simply drag the file BRUNSWICK_1106_TreeTops.shp into your QGIS project.** It should load with geometry *and* attributes. Geometry will be displayed on your map canvas. To see the attributes, [open the attribute table](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#introducing-the-attribute-table-interface). You can now remove the .dbf file from your project (right click on it in the layer panel > remove layer).